# vqmod doesn't create catalog/controller cache files

Tags: opencart, vqmod

I'm trying to write my vqmod .xml, but nothing to work? if I try to add change in all catalog/* files. It works good for other (system/*, admin/*) files, but nothing changes? if I try to do something like this:

```
<file name="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
      $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? count($this->session->data['vouchers']) : 0), $this->currency->format($total));
      ]]></search>
        <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
      $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? count($this->session->data['vouchers']) : 0), $this->currency->format($total));
      ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is Your vQmod log saying? Anyway replacing a line of code with the very same line of code is really hard to notice to happen...

Comment: my Vqmod logs is empty, but if i make mistake,  
e.c. in <file name="catalog/**mistake**">, log file alert error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to try:

1. Check whether vqmod is installed by calling
   https://domain.com/vqmod/install in browser. If not installed, then
   install and check.
2. Verify file name and path, also confirm that the code in search tag
   exists in the file mentioned.
3. Check folder permissions. Make sure that vqmod/vqcache and
   vqmod/logs have 755 or 777 permission. If nothing works, then try
   777 permission recursively for vqmod folder.
4. Check the error logs in  vqmod/logs.
5. Check the installed vqmod version and the vqmod version given in xml
       file (`<vqmver><![CDATA[version]]></vqmver>`), both need to be the
       same.
6. Delete the files in vqmod/vqcache and check again. Also see whether
   vqmod copy of your file is generated or not.
7. Move any vqmod xml file outside the vqmod folder and check. If
   everything works, move the xml back to the vqmod folder. I don’t
   know the reason, but it worked for me in some cases :) !
8. `<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”UTF-8″?>` – put this line at the top of
   the XML to make it valid and more compatible.
9. Try the VQMod Manager extension. It may help you!

Reference url: **[Opencart: Vqmod tutorial](https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/)**

Comment: 1) VQMOD ALREADY INSTALLED!
2) Verified - error log is empty.
3) Checked. Another .xml are working correctly.
4) Error log is empty (I correct all errors in case)
5) Done. Nothing changed :(
6) Done. Nothing :(
7) Put
8) I'm alredy use vqmod manager...

Comment: Sorry.. problem was in <vqmver><![CDATA[*version*]]></vqmver> parametr.. It was older, then my current vqmver :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the search can be found, you're not doing anything wrong. However, if it's only the catalog side that is having an issue, then it's most likely your opencart `index.php` for the catalog side doesn't have vQmod installed whereas the admin side does. Check your `index.php` file is correct. If that is written, then clear your vqcache folder to ensure it's actually writeable

Comment: Sorry.. problem was on <vqmver><![CDATA[_version_]]></vqmver> parametr.. It was older, then my current vqmver :(